# arm cortex-m4 hardfault when using -ffast-math

Tags: assembly, arm, gdb, interrupt

I'm trying to launch simple LED blinking application, all works fine but if I add -ffast-math, it goes to hard fault. I debugged via GDB and found that if I add -ffast-math, it inserts call to __arm_set_fast_math from __libc_init_array as part of initialization routine (from .init_array section)

Disassembling __arm_set_fast_math shows:

```
080001f4 <__arm_set_fast_math>:
 80001f4:       eef1 3a10       vmrs    r3, fpscr
 80001f8:       f043 7380       orr.w   r3, r3, #16777216       ;0x1000000
 80001fc:       eee1 3a10       vmsr    fpscr, r3
 8000200:       4770            bx      lr
 8000202:       bf00            nop
```

According GDB:

```
0x080001f4 in __arm_set_fast_math ()
(gdb) stepi
HardFault_Handler () at src/stm32f4xx_it.c:61
```

it jumps to hardFault handler immediately. removing --fast-math fixes everything. any idea? thanks!

Comment: I assume the fault is an illegal-instruction fault?  Also that your CPU doesn't have a hardware FPU?  Is there some reason you want to use `-ffast-math`?  Are you using software-emulated floating-point?

Comment: I have mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16, and -ffast-math just came with template that I got, took 2 days to debug it and now I want to know why it caused such behaviour. fault is "hard fault"

Comment: Did that build template come from your hardware vendor directly?  Or was it just something you found?  In any case, this documents the FPSCR layout: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344b/Chdfafia.html.  That fast-math init function is setting the FZ bit (flush denormals to zero), which presumably speeds up the FPU when it would have produced a denormal.

Comment: but M4 (core I'm using) also has same register:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABBFJEC.html
and I'm trying to figure out why why it hardfaults

Comment: Without `-ffast-math`, do you get a hard fault when you compile code that does FP math?  Like `double x = 1.111, y=2.33;`   `double z = x * y;` (and compile with `-O0`, or use `volatile` or something so it's not evaluated at compile time.)

Comment: no, it works fine

Comment: You should edit some of that into your question.  It's important that regular VFP math instructions work, but `vmrs` doesn't.  (It would be good if you could show disassembly of a specific VFP instruction that does work as part of your `main()` function.)  And also list the exact build options you're using, in the question for other people to see.  IDK the answer myself.  `vmrs` is supposed to work for CPUs that support VFP, I think.  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204h/Bcfbdihi.html

Comment: What is the specific CPU chip you're using?

Comment: did you enable the coprocessor(s) so that they will execute floating point?  they generally power up disabled.

Comment: does the cpuid registers for your chip show that the vendor included the floating point unit?